# Viewing source code from a third-party jar in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, reverse-engineering

I am working on a Java project in Eclipse. In this I am using a third party JAR which I have put in on the classpath. Now I want to understand the code in the JAR file and want to see the actual code and navigate through the third party code just like my own code.

My question is this: Instead of me manually decompiling all of the class files in the JAR and putting them in the appropriate folder as per package declaration, is there some way in which Eclipse will decompile them for me, and put them in the appropriate folder? What should be the approach taken in such a scenario?

Comment: reverse engineering should not be done without author's permission.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor  ...who told you it is reverse engineering??? Basically the third party jar has been written by an employee of our own company who has now left the organization. He has not commited the actual source code in the repository but only left the compiled jar file. Now i need to extend the functionality and so see the code in the jar file to modify the existing jar files. This has nothing to do with reverse engineering.

Comment: @user496934, reverse engineering is not always bad, in your case it is understandable. :-)

Comment: Yeah ..reverse engineering is not always bad -:) But i dont think that what I am doing is reverse engineering. I only want to extend the existing functionality and so I want to see the existing implementation.

Comment: @user496934: sad to hear that you had such irresponsible employee. I fully understand your frustration. JAD is a good choice, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decompiler I use is JAD. It has an eclipse plugin, Jadclipse.

You can download JAD from http://www.varaneckas.com/jad

You can get Jadclipse from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/. Click on the download jar and then simply copy the jar into your Eclipse/plugins directory, and restart Eclipse. Set up the path to JAD from Preferences->Java->JADClipse. Then trying to view a class should give the decompiled code.

Comment: Sometimes you need check if .class files are asociated with JadClipse. Just check in Preferences -> General -> Editor -> File Asociations and set as default jadclipse in ".class" and ".class without source".

Comment: As far as I can tell, this tool and only unpack a '.class' file and gives error msg when trying to unpack a '.jar' file

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Java Decompiler for some time and have found it very useful, i don't know about eclipse but it seems to have a eclipse plugin: [JD-Eclipse](http://jd.benow.ca/)